# How do I look up a value from an Excel Power Query and put it into another Excel Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I'm just discovering Power Query in Excel, but have got stuck.  I have a product code in query1 and the same code with its description in query2.  I want to add the description from query2 into query1, but just cannot see how to do it.   Normally I would just use a VLOOKUP, but it doesn't seem so simple in Power Query.  Any help appreciated. :0)

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling, I’m going to answer my own question with how I ended up doing it, in case it may help others.  There may be another ways, but this worked for me:

Assuming you have loaded your query (in this case, Query1) into a spreadsheet…
If the Workbook Queries pane is not visible on the right-hand side of your spreadsheet, click the Data tab and click Show Queries in the Get and Transform group.

Right click on the query in the Workbook Queries pane that you wish to add the ‘looked up’ column into (in this case, Query1) and click Edit.

Now click on Merge Queries in the Home ribbon. Columns from your first query (in this case, Query1) appear in the top pane. Highlight the code column.  In the bottom pane, select the query your value to be looked up is in (in this case, Query2), then highlight its code column.  Click OK.

An additional column now appears next to the last column in your first query with a header of in this case, Query2 and a value of ‘Table’.

Left click the icon to the right in the new header and a list of column headers appears.  Tick the column(s) you want to add to your query (in this case, Code Desc).  You can them drag the new column to wherever you want it in your query.